# Basic Big-O Question

Tags: asymptotics

I had 2 very small queries regarding Big-O notation:

- If $f(x) = O(g(x))$, then for any constant a, is it the case that $a^{f(x)} = O(a^{g(x)})$?
- If $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and $h(x) = O(i(x))$, then does $h(x)^{f(x)} = O(i(x)^{g(x)})$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Consider the counterexample $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=2x$, $h(x)=i(x)=a=2$.

Comment: Isn't $2^x = O(2^{2x})$?

Comment: Suppose $2^x = O(2^{2x})$. Then exists $C>0$ such that $C\cdot 2^x > 2^{2x}=4^x$ for all $x>0$. It follows that $C > 2^x$, a contradiction.

Comment: It is the other way around: $ 2^x\leq C 2^{2x}$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, consider for example $f(x)=\ln x$, $g(x)=x$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$. Then
\begin{align}
\ln x=O(x)
\end{align}
as $x\to\infty$. But it is not true that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2^{\ln x}}=O\bigg(\frac{1}{2^x}\bigg)
\end{align}
as $x\to\infty$.

For the second, take $f(x)=1,\forall x$ and $g(x)=x$. Also $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $i(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then we have
\begin{align}
h(x)^{f(x)}&=\frac{1}{x^2};\\
i(x)^{g(x)}&=\frac{1}{x^x}
\end{align}
But $\frac{1}{x^x}=O(\frac{1}{x^2})$, as $x\to\infty$.